# New .NET 3.5 Project: Which DAL technology to use?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, dataset, enterprise-library, data-access-layer

I am preparing a new Windows project and wonder what kind of DAL technology to use. Originally I was looking for something simpler to not spending too much time on building it. But I understand also that it has to be efficient and scalable in the long run.

I plan to use WPF (MVVM) Client and WCF Service on a 3 Tier system.

Just to sum up all the existing technologies I am familiar with:

**DataSets**

PRO: Might be a bit old fashioned, but very easy to use and let the most parts to be auto generated for you. One powerful aspect about datasets are the ease of traversing related data through the Relations. Also in a way its disconnected from database and might simplify the updates by taking care of timestamps automatically. Includes validation.

CONTRA: Quite old fashioned. Some consider them as no real business objects/Models but just a mirror of your SQL data tables. Passing them between WCF Service/Client might be more difficult than self created business objects.

**Enterprise Library 4.1 - Data Access Block**

PRO: The DAL is beautifully put into a Factory pattern. It takes care of connection opening and closing automatically. Very easy to use for most part. It supports both dataSets and normal SQL Sps to create your own Business objects. As part of an ongoing Framework it can be much more efficient to use in combination with rest of the Enterprise Library for an efficient end product.

CONTRA: ??

**Linq to SQL**

PRO: Auto creates the SQL tables into business objects. Easy to CRUD. Theoretically a very nice way to do it.

CONTRA: Having played around with it when it came out, I found it flaky and sometimes instable. It is already considered a dead technology after Microsoft announcement that Entity Framework 4.0 - as part of .NET 4.0 - will be Microsoft recommended way. Only few bug fixes are too be expected in .NET 4.0 but no more feature extending plans.

**Entity Framework 4.0**

I don't know anything about it, but only that it will eventually replace everything else as on .NET 4.0. I am also tempted to use it, however since its still in BETA, I wouldnt be able to go that way yet.

I am very tempted to use Enterprise Library 4.1 - Data Access Block and to create my own business objects. The big Con is that it will take more time to create the DAL.  Unless someone can convince me of using DataSets through the Data Access Block instead.

What are your comments and ideas?
Many Thanks,
Kave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention Entity Framework as part of the "contra" for the Linq to SQL option, but you should consider it in place of Linq to SQL -- it provides pretty much the same functionality plus more.  For projects with smaller databases it definitely provides a lot of bang for the buck.  It can be challenging in EF to manage the context for larger databases, and schema changes can cause things to break, but these challenges are there with any data access approach.

The biggest con for EntLib, in my  mind, is that you are still rolling your own data objects.  The Enterprise Library takes away a lot of the plumbing code from a straight "old-school" ADO.NET implementation, which is nice, but it doesn't generate data objects for you that can be used out of the box for LINQ querying.

Comment: I was giving it some thoughts and I think you are right. Using EntLib still means a lot of work creating everything by hand.
When you mentioned EF, did you mean version 4.0 BETA or do you mean the actual version 1.0? I have been actually trying version 1.0 last night and I must say it looks quite alright and does the job.  Just before that I tried SubSonic, which failed creating code for my lookup tables, that had the same name as one of their existing fields. This must have confused Subsonic. EF 1.0 did the job perfectly fine and I think I will go this way. What do you think?

Comment: EF 1 is not anywhere near as feature rich as LinqToSql and LinqToSql is pretty poor feature wise.  EF 1 is missing support for basic ORM concepts like proper lazy loading support, which LinqToSql does support.

Comment: I have used EF 1.0 for a few apps, ones with smaller databases and that were not performance critical, and have been happy enough with it -- the basic requirement was, "get the data into and out of the database".  If features, scalability and performance are a big concern, you could still definitely try EF, but might want to abstract data access using another software layer, or something like CSLA, so that you could switch or upgrade data access technologies later.

Of course, at that point, the RAD benefits might not be there anymore and you may want to consider a full custom stack.

Comment: Hi Guy, being less than 4 months away until EF 4.0 is released, I think I can focus on front end and business layer for now and mock the DAL until its released.  Even though if I had to go for a repository for now, I decided to stick with MS technology. The time investing in a third party software is now not really worth it, considering EF 4.0 will push even nhibernate away. Since lazy loading and asynch data loading is important to me and having a simple database schema, I think I choose Linq2Sql rather than EF1.0. I am sure MS will provide us with conversion wizards to upgrade to EF4 anyway

Answer (score 2):

We prevously used DataSets with EntLib 4.1 Data Application Block.

We now use Entity Framework. We have achived a massive improvement in productivity with Entity Framework compared with EntLib 4.1. (Progam the data layer for 80 tables in 10 hours instead of 80)

Entity Framework 4 is still in Beta, but if it is a while before your project goes live, I would go with EF 4. You get the productivity of an ORM at the same time the flexibility of using POCO (Plain Old Clr Objects)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Was that EF 1.0 or EF 4.0 Beta you have used?

Comment: @Kave, it was EF 1.0, but we started using it while it was in Beta

Answer (score 1):

A. Check also NHibernate.

B. DataSet - the fastest and easiest, but you code a lot.

All the rest - there is a lot good in using ORM tools, but there is a lot of problems with 3 tiering with them.

(lazy loading is a problem to deal with, making a lot of big object trees that effect performance, caching is not as smart as possible)

So - it depends what is your major needs, and how much time you want to spend studying EL/LINQ or NHibernate before you start coding, b/c there IS a learning curve with this tools.

Answer (score 1):

Best idea is to have opportunity to use both technologies at the same time.
How can you do it? It is very simple with Repository pattern. 
At first you need create generic IRepository interface.  Something likes this:

```
public interface IERepository<E>
{
    DbTransaction BeginTransaction();
    void EndTransaction();
    void Add(E entity);
    void Delete(E entity);
    int Save();

    ObjectQuery<E> DoQuery(string entitySetName);
    IList<E> SelectAll(string entitySetName);
    E SelectByKey(int Key);

    bool TrySameValueExist(string fieldName, object fieldValue, string key);
    bool TryEntity(ISpecification<E> selectSpec);

    int GetCount();
    int GetCount(ISpecification<E> selectSpec);
    int AddAndSave(E entity);

}
```

I prefer Entity Framework. I created 3 projects based on it. It works very fast, especially queries with paging. 
So, after you need create base generic class Repository with virtual methods what implement IRepository interface. And that’s all.
 Now you have very fast way to create DAl writing simple code like this:

```
public class MonthRepository:Repository<Month>
{

}
```

You have possibility to override all methods of base class and create access to DB using stored procedure where you need. And you can do with without changing code in other places. Your will still return the same type of entities but will get them in other way.

Reade more on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx

Comment: Thanks mate. This solutions sounds indeed interesting if it would give me more flexibility to interchange the Repository. I still need to understand it first though. Give me a few days to study it afetr work please. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate has the best overall mix of feature set, maturity, and support.

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

You should consider Linq support a priority for any solution you consider and your first two options above do not support Linq.

Comment: Hi Michael,

I was also reading about NHibernate. I found the documentation not as straight forward and it seems to be a very complicated application to run. Unless you know of some walkthorugh websites I don't know of yet, I feel a bit lost there.  Unfortunatelly SubSonic didn't work for me due a bug. There is still the Castle Project I could try, or just stick to MS solutions such as EF 1.0 hoping to upgrade soon to v4.0 once available.

Comment: If you can't find your way around NHibernate, you aren't likely to get what you need from LinqToSql or EntityFramework either.  NHibernate's documentation isn't really worse than any other ORM's documentation.  There is a learning curve to any ORM, NHibernate's curve currently just starts sooner.  NHibernate is likely to meet your requirements while the others are likely to only meet your requirements until a certain point and then you end up starting over with NHibernate anyway.  Ultimately, it's your call and your responsibility.

Comment: Thanks Michael. What do you think of that Fluent NHibernate? Is it a kind of wizard to get the mapping generated for me automatically? Are there any helping tools to make life easier with NHibernate?

Comment: Fluent NHibernate doesn't do any code generation, but it allows you to use C# for the mappings instead of XML.  See here for NHibernate code generation options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703254/nhibernate-code-generation  CodeSmith seems like the best option right now.