# Moving to Mono : Entity Framework alternatives

Tags: entity-framework, mono

We've been working on in VS2010 and EF and various discussions around scalability and costing have led us to look into moving to Mono.

I understand almost all of my code would be functional, except the EF that we're using for our model (ASP.NET project).

Can anyone recommend an easy to use ORM that will allow us to do much of the same mapping (Foreign Keys etc) operations with MySQL? One thing I did like was the visual element of the EF modeling, making it very simple to make changes and see relationships.

Comment: NHibernate (not really easy to use).

Comment: @Steven - NHibernate and Entity Framework are in the same ballpark complexity-wise.  If you choose to hand write your XML mapping files, NHibernate is a slower start than Entity Framework, but there is no good reason to do that.

Comment: In relation to "writing your XML mapping files" - are you saying there are tools which would help us map these out automatically? If so, can you point me in the direction of these?

Comment: @Michael: I admit, EF can be a PITA too.

Comment: @pierre FluentNHibernate will relive the burden of XML (http://fluentnhibernate.org)

Comment: Can't mark these comments as answers(?) but FluentNHibernate looks great.

Comment: @pierre: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703254/nhibernate-code-generation - I have a commercial tool available for $30 at AgilityForORMs.com, but google searching should find you plenty of options, some free, some commercial.  YMMV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that EF is open source, you can likely expect it to be usable with Mono soon

http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Entity-Framework-goes-to-opensource-td4650600.html

Comment: This was just announced today :) http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-13.html

Answer (score 17):

Mono 2.11.3 now comes bundled with Entity Framework. This is just a preview release, but the upcoming 2.12 release should fully support Entity Framework :)

See http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-13.html

Answer (score 1):

As written, there is no answer to your question because it is ill-formed.  In the title, you mention wanting an "Entity Framework alternative", but your latter comments indicate you're looking for more than what the Entity Framework provides--so even if one existed it would not give you everything you wanted.

Without more specifics, it appears you want to say something more akin to:

- How can I use MySQL and Visual Studio to get an equivalently well-integrated experience as I currently do with SQL Server (or other commercial DB)?
- Which alternative databases and EF-compatible ORMs can I use to get an equivalent design-time experience with MySQL (or another open-source DB) compared to what I currently get with SQL Server (or other commercial DB)?
- How can I get an equivalently well-integrated Visual Studio debugging, design-time  and development experience on a lower cost non-Windows (e.g. Linux) platform?

Depending on which of the above your question(s) is actually closer to, will dictate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Today I [tried](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/04/14/entity-framework-6-on-mono/) Entity Framework 6 alpha2 with Mono. It's not quite there yet but I believe the issues can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not much complex, Castle ActiveRecord is one of the alternatives. Even though it does not provide FK relationship, it is way easier to use than NHibernate. For instance, AR provide the annotation based configuration instead of verbose XML configuration.

Comment: Castle ActiveRecord does fine with foreign key relationships.  What are you referring to?

Comment: Does Castle ActiveRecord support LINQ over IQueryable queries?

Comment: @Michael - I meant [ForeignKey] attribute in EF it makes more handy when saving a parent-child object, on the other hand, there is [BelongsTo] attribute in AR, but it is used for reference type not primitive type as far as I know. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Steven Yes, please refer following URL, it is testcase for ActiveRecordLinq : https://github.com/castleproject/ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord.Tests/ActiveRecordLinqTestCase.cs

Comment: Note that Castle ActiveRecord is no longer an active project, so I don't think there's going to be any more development on it. It's listed as an archived project at http://www.castleproject.org/projects/